# Remove empty P tags from HTML?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I am trying to strip empty `<P>` tags from a block of HTML within a Shopify theme. For some reason the `remove` filter is not detecting whatever the space character is inside the tag. I've even tried copy/pasting from source code into my command and it's not working.

```
{{ article.content | remove: '<p> </p>' | remove: '<p>&nbsp;</p>' }}
```

With this, it still remains:

[image: Screenshot showing P tags still there after remove]

Copy/paste of the pesky tag:

```
<p> </p>
```

Comment: Did you check final rendered HTML code. How empty <p> </p> are rendered? It might help.

Comment: I have tried replacing all occurances of space with another character but still `<p> </p>` remains in the HTML. It seems to be some other kind of space character coming out of Shopify.

Comment: That's not what I've asked ;). On the front of the website, how these empty <p> tags are displayed in source code?

Comment: There is a screenshot of the source code in the original answer. The P tags appear normally.

Comment: Would you please post code instead of screenshot?

Comment: Sure, copy/paste into the message one of the P tags that won't remove.

Comment: I think I found somtehing (answer below).

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide all empty paragraphs with the following CSS:

```css
p:empty {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**replace**

Replaces all occurrences of a string with a substring.

```
{{ article.content | replace: '<p> </p>', '' }}
```

Comment: I've also tried to replace them, it doesn't work. What looks like a standard space (even in View Source) seems to be something else that the command is not matching.

Comment: I tried this method and it worked in my testing store. Since it is not working for you, maybe you could try encoding the string before rendering to see if you can work out what character is being rendered between your tags?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found something by copying source code from article editor in Sublime Text.
If you try this (not tested) does it work better?

```
{{ article.content | remove: '<p><0xa0></p>' }}
```

Comment: Not working either. Tough one.